# TypeError: Joi.string(...).custom is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I want to add custom validation, but I get an error while I add custom

```
function isValidInput(value) {
  const regex = /<[^>]*>|javascript:/gi;
  if (regex.test(value)) {
    throw new Error('Input contains HTML tags or scripts');
  }
}
 module.exports.placeOrder = Joi.object({
  buyer: Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().guid().required(),
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  }).required(),
  organisation: Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().required(),
    title: Joi.string().required(),
  }).required(),
  updated_by: Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().guid().required(),
    name: Joi.string().allow(null),
    email: Joi.string().allow(null),
  }).required(),
  program: Joi.array()
    .items(
      Joi.object({
        id: Joi.string()
          .regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+={0,2}$/)
          .required(),
        producer: Joi.object({
          id: Joi.string().guid().required(),
          name: Joi.string().custom(isValidInput).required().allow(null),
          email: Joi.string().email().allow(null),
        }).required(),
        channel_partner: Joi.object({
          id: Joi.string().guid().required(),
          name: Joi.string().required(),
          email: Joi.string().required(),
        }).required(),
        igpid: Joi.string()
          .regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+={0,2}$/)
          .optional(),
        title: Joi.string().required(),
        description: Joi.string().optional(),
        initial_units: Joi.number().integer().required(),
        program_source: Joi.string().required(),
        genome_insight: Joi.string().optional(),
        reach: Joi.number().integer().required(),
        available_units: Joi.number().integer().optional(),
        status: Joi.string().required(),
        sdg: Joi.object({
          program_sdg_names: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).required(),
          program_sdg_targets: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).required(),
        }).optional(),
       })
      )
      .required(),
   });
```

I want to add custom validation so that no external HTML tags or script is injected. I want to ensure no malicious script could be injected into the request. I'v got an error in the validation while I was using the JOi version 14.

Comment: Did you try _`custom`_?

Comment: @tkausl Yes but same error as when I import Joi this error occurs and when I import @hapi/joi it throw this error  message  "Invalid schema content: ($_root.alternatives)"

Comment: Not sure if related, but your custom validation should return the value unchanged when no validation errors occurred. Note: if the method fails to return a value, the value will be unset or returned as undefined.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I got the error .custom() is not a function then how custom validation function is called first it should be called after that the custom validation called.

Comment: I said it may not be related, but you still have other errors in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved Issue: Using Joi Version 14 versus Version 17

I experienced an issue in my project and successfully handled it, and I wanted to share the answer here in case anyone else runs into a similar situation.

The issue arose from utilizing an out-of-date version of Joi (version 14) in my project. The functionality I wanted, custom(), was unavailable in version 14. However, it was included in version 17.

After upgrading to the most recent version of Joi (version 17), everything reverted to normal, and I was able to use the custom() method as intended.

If you are experiencing similar problems with Joi, I suggest you upgrade to the most recent version to access all of the new features and bug fixes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).